# Esconder "boton, pagina, etc" si el usuario no es admin-role ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, users-roles

Resulta que estoy iniciando sesion en una pagina, esta inicia y todo:

**INICIA SESION**

```
//RETORNO LOGIN
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LogIn(string usuario, string password)
        {
            if (usuario == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usuario, false);
                return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(-1);
            }
        }
```

Cuando entra al home se desplega el `_layout`, pero este mismo tiene una barra lateral donde quiero mostrar la diferentes paginas que va a tener la pagina, resulta que quiero ocultar una que solo se muestre si el que entra es un admin:

```
          <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="../gallery.html" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="nav-icon far fa-image"></i>
                    <p>
                        Miscelaneos
                    </p>
                </a>
            </li>
      @if(Roles.IsUserInRole("admin")) //disque esto se muestra si es admin
            {
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="../gallery.html" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon far fa-image"></i>
                        <p>
                            Sistema
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
```

Por lo cual al ingresar en el metodo que me loguea agrego la siguiente linea `Roles.AddUserToRole("admin", "Admin");`

```
//RETORNO LOGIN
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LogIn(string usuario, string password)
        {
            if (usuario == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usuario, false);
               //LINEA NUEVA 
                Roles.AddUserToRole("admin", "Admin");
                return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(-1);
            }
        }
```

Al correr la pagina, me lanza este error en la linea `Roles.AddUserToRole("admin", "Admin");` :

> System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: 'La característica
>   Administrador de roles no está habilitada.'

Segun lo cual se "resuelve" agregando lo siguiente en `Web.Config` en `<system.web>`:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

Al arrancar nuevamente me sale el siguiente error en la pagina:

> No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'MySql.ConnectorInstaller,
>   Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' ni
>   una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo
>   especificado.

1- Cual es la forma de asignar roles o permitir que cierto usuario (todo lo diferente a admin) pueda ver o no contenido de la pagina?

2- ¿A que se debe el error que lanza al final?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error:

> System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: 'La característica Administrador de roles no está habilitada.'

Se resuelve agregando:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.Enabled
```

Y acto seguido, en el `web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> 1- ¿Cuál es la forma de asignar roles o permitir que cierto usuario (todo lo diferente a admin) pueda ver o no contenido de la página?

La asignación de roles depende de la lógica de negocios, lo podrías hacer hasta como proyecto de consola que genere los usuarios en la misma tabla que vas a usar en la aplicación web.

Lo que se recomienda es que se tenga algún usuario del tipo "super administrador" que realice dichas configuraciones. El tema es bastante amplio, revisa el siguiente enlace para que te hagas una idea: http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/

Revisa sobre los **Action Filters**, en especial sobre este: **Authorize**

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters

Del enlace, aquí un ejemplo:

**CustomAuthenticationAttribute**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext) {

    //For demo purpose only. In real life your custom principal might be retrieved via different source. i.e context/request etc.
    filterContext.Principal = new MyCustomPrincipal(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity, new []{"Admin"}, "Red");
}

public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext) {
    var color = ((MyCustomPrincipal) filterContext.HttpContext.User).HairColor;
    var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthentication]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Aqui otro ejemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Y la parte que debería ser la favorita de todo desarrollador, la documentación:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

2- ¿A que se debe el error que lanza al final?

El error que tienes con mysql:

> No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'MySql.ConnectorInstaller, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Se resuelve instalando el **connector** http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/